# PHP date to timestamp conversion not working as expected

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have following function which should just add number of weeks to the start date and return the end date, however i get wrong end date for values greater than 20 ,

for example the

start date='2013-05-30'
interval_term=24;

will return as

end date: 2013-11-07

function is like below,

```
public function calculateArrangementEndDate($interval_term=12,$start_date=false)
{
    $end_date=($start_date===false)?time():strtotime($start_date);
    return date("Y-m-d",($end_date+($interval_term-1)*3600*7*24));
}
```

but the correct 24 weeks from the start_date is 
2013-10-31

like this

Payment Schedule:

```
Due Date       Amount
30/05/2013     $0.64
06/06/2013     $0.64
13/06/2013     $0.64
20/06/2013     $0.64
27/06/2013     $0.64
04/07/2013     $0.64
11/07/2013     $0.64
18/07/2013     $0.64
25/07/2013     $0.64
01/08/2013     $0.64
08/08/2013     $0.64
15/08/2013     $0.64
22/08/2013     $0.64
29/08/2013     $0.64
05/09/2013     $0.64
12/09/2013     $0.64
19/09/2013     $0.64
26/09/2013     $0.64
03/10/2013     $0.64
10/10/2013     $0.64
17/10/2013     $0.64
24/10/2013     $0.64
31/10/2013     $0.64
```

Comment: Have you considered just using http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: isnt that 24 weeks should be 31/10/2013 like the above schedule ?

Answer (score 0):

I though that the easy way is using strtotime to add this 24 weeks instead use

```
$enddate = strtotime('2013-05-30 00:00:00 +24 weeks');
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $enddate));
```

Will return "2013-11-14 00:00:00"

If you try with 2 weeks for easy test you will get 2013-06-13 00:00:00 and this is exactly 14 days more.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand the difference between your start date and the first due date - is the first one counted in the 24 months? If so, then do you want the term to actually be 23 months? [24 weeks after 30/05/2013 is indeed 14/11/2013](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?m1=05&d1=30&y1=2013&type=add&ay=&am=&ad=&aw=24).

You also have only 23 dates listed in your payment schedule (but starting from the start date, not using that as the first due date, if that makes sense).

Finally, I'd suggest using the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead. Here's an example:

```
public function calculateArrangementEndDate($interval_term=12,$start_date=false)
{
  $date = new DateTime($start_date);
  if (is_null($date)) {
    // throw exception or return false here
  }
  
  $date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $interval_term . 'W'));
  return $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

This will work out the date `$interval_term` weeks from `$start_date` - the first two points remain.

```
var_dump(
  calculateArrangementEndDate(23, '2013-05-30')
);
// string(10) "2013-11-07"
```

Comment: nope i had the -1 to the interval term in the function and it returns 2013-11-07; while as you see in the payment schedule its coming to end in the 2013-10-31; even i replce to your one i still get the same error which i dont knw why its week ahead when i already deducted a -1

Comment: on the otherhand if i deducted -2 from the interval, then for a 4 weeks schedule will return 2013-6-13, which is week below the correct date...

Comment: If 30/05/2013 is your start date, then 31/10/2013 is 22 weeks later. That's incorrect if you want it to be 24 weeks. 23 weeks after 31/10/2013 is 07/11/2013. The line **but the correct 24 weeks from the start_date is 2013-10-31** is incorrect - it is 22 weeks, *or* if you include the first week it's 23 - but that would make the real start date a week before - which is 23/05/2013.

Comment: (and if you want to do that, I'd just add a `$interval_term--` in to the top of the function. But really you need to understand what you are doing as opposed to what you're trying to do.